# Find maximum area (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, area

Consider the code below (MatLab):

```
w = 0 : 0.0001 : 9.4978;
a = [1    11    46    95   109    74    24];
b = [-1 3 4 3 1];
mu = 1;
a0 = a(7) ;a1 = a(6) ;a2 = a(5); a3 = a(4) ; a4 = a(3) ; a5 = a(2); a6 = a(1);
b0 = b(5);b1 = b(4);b2 = b(3) ; b3 = b(2); b4 = b(1) ;
De = -a6*w.^6 + a4*w.^4 - a2*w.^2 + a0;
Do = a5*w.^4 - a3*w.^2 + a1;
Ne = b4*w.^4 - b2*w.^2 + b0;
No = -b3*w.^2 + b1;
T = 0.01;
e = real((1i*w).^mu);
f = imag((1i*w).^mu);
A = Ne.*cos(T*w) + w.*No.*sin(T*w);  
B = e.*(Ne.*cos(T*w) + w.*No.*sin(T*w)) - f.*(w.*No.*cos(T*w) - Ne.*sin(T*w));
C = w.*No.*cos(T*w) - Ne.*sin(T*w);
D = e.*(w.*No.*cos(T*w) - Ne.*sin(T*w)) + f.*(Ne.*cos(T*w) + w.*No.*sin(T*w));
Kp = (-De.*D + w.*Do.*B)./(f.*(Ne.^2 + w.^2.*No.^2));
Kd = (-w.*Do.*A + De.*C)./(f.*(Ne.^2 + w.^2.*No.^2));
figure
plot(Kp,Kd)
line([-24 -24],[-2.24 9.813])
```

By running code we have this figure: 
[image]

I want to draw tangent lines on specified part of curve ( **red part**, w belongs to [0.6342,0.9985] ) : 
[image]

after doing that, my aim is to find **maximum area** of inward-pointing half plane defined by this line and curve between all possible areas which produced by tangent line(like this):
[image]

another example with another tangent line at another point is:

[image]

and we can conclude first area is bigger than the second one. This approach should do for all points in red part.

How can I do it by MatLab?

I hope my question is clear. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you had in mind to solve this? Is this really a programming issue?

Comment: This is a little ambiguous: "want to draw tangent lines on specified part of curve". You mean you want to draw a tangent at a *specific*  point, **or** a bunch or tangents at a bunch of points in that stretch? Plus as EitanT points out, this is first a geometry problem. Once you solve that you can think about the programming. You may also want to consider using image processing tools to performing the task, if this is a graphical exercise.

Comment: @EitanT I don't sure how to do it. That is why I posted this.

Comment: @Zia But how is this really related to MALTAB? It's a theoretical problem. Once you figure out an approach to solving it, you can give it a go in MATLAB.

Comment: @TryHard I mean I want to draw "n tangent line at n distinct (but Consecutive) point"(n point belong to red part of curve). After searching among n area produced by n tangent line, determine maximum area and tangent line related to maximum area. (tangents at a bunch of points in red part). But I can't understand why you note this is a geometrical problem? What is your suggestion to using image processing tools?

Comment: @TryHard I added more details.

Comment: I would try to solve it as follows: 1) determine all possible tangents and use them to define triangles in the lower left corner. 2) Determine the overlapping area of the triangles and the original shape and relate them to the area of the original shape A_color = A_original-A_overlap. For both steps you will find solutions here on SO or at Matlab Central. Maybe also function `polyarea` helps you.

Comment: It is a geometry problem because you have to find the points of intersection of the tangent and original curves... Off the top of my head I would start by breaking down the implicitly defined curve (f(t),g(t)) into two curves y1 = h1(x) and y2 = h2(x), and solve for the intersection points. Then write an expression for the area in terms of these which you can maximize in matlab using optimization.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Could you explain what is your mean of overlapping area?

Comment: have a look at my solution now, does that look reasonable? @Try-Hard,Eitan-T: simplifications welcome!

Comment: @TryHard What is your comment about the answer released by thewaywewalk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work somehow.

```
% remove NaNs
Kd(1)=[];
Kp(1)=[];
%%

%exclude non relavant part of original curve
x=Kp;
y=Kd;
exc = 40000;
x(exc:1:end)=[];
y(exc:1:end)=[];

mask = find(x < -9 & x > -19);
xs = x(mask);
ys = y(mask);

L = length(xs)
%%
% determine area of original shape
A_total = polyarea(Kd,Kp);

% pre-allocation    
slope=zeros(L,1)';
inter = slope;
A_part = slope;

for ii = 1:1:L;
    % determine slope for every point
    xslope = xs(ii);
    idx_a = find(xs<xslope,1,'last');
    idx_b = find(xs>xslope,1,'first');
    xa = xs(idx_a);
    xb = xs(idx_b);
    slope(ii) = (ys(idx_b) - ys(idx_a))/(xb - xa);

    % determine slope between current point and any other one
    slopeX = (ys(ii)-y)./(xs(ii)-x);
    % determine intersection points of tangent with rest of curve
    [~,intersection] = min(abs((slopeX)-slope(ii)));
    % index of intersection
    inter(ii)=intersection;
end

% modify curve to get polygon
x_start = x(1);
x_end = x_start;
y_start = y(1);


%finally calculate all single area values A(ii)
for ii = 1:1:L;
    i_inter = inter(ii);
    y_end = y(i_inter) - (x(i_inter)- x_end)*slope(ii);
    x(i_inter+1) = x_end;
    y(i_inter+1) = y_end;
    A_part(ii) = A_total - polyarea( x(1:1:i_inter+1) ,y(1:1:i_inter+1) );
end
```

When you plot now `A_part` over `x` you get:

[image]

as a proof here all tangents:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's seems reasonable. But I should check this much. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zia hopefully last correction... don't worry I really like this question.

Comment: It's a nice numerical approach but the last part (determination of the area to exclude) doesn't appear to be quite right. Try for instance overlaying `plot(x(1:1:i_inter+1) ,y(1:1:i_inter+1),'r:')` onto the original curve...

Comment: @TryHard you're right, I had another look at it. In the second plot you can see all tangents, now it seems right. (really!) :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk looks much better! :)